# Existence of a strongly regular vertex ordering on cubic graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

**Definition:** Let $G=(V,E)$ be a cubic (i.e. $3$-regular) graph, and $<$ a total order on $V$. For $v\in V$ let $v^\downarrow$ denote the set of nodes $w\in V$ such that $w<v$, and let $\alpha(v) = |N_v\cap v^\downarrow|$ be the number of neighbors of $v$ preceding $v$. For each $i$ let $D(i)$ denote the set of nodes $v\in V$ such that $\alpha(v)=i$. We say the ordering $<$ is *strongly regular* if $|D(0)| = 1$ and $|D(2)|\leqslant 1$.

**Question:** Does every connected cubic graph have a strongly regular ordering? If not, does every $3$-connected cubic Levi graph (i.e., bipartite graph of girth at least $6$) have a strongly regular ordering? What about $3$-connected cubic Hamiltonian graphs?

It's easy to show that any connected cubic graph has an ordering such that $|D(0)|=1$. A natural attempt to prove existence would hypothesize that $<$ is a total ordering that minimizes $|D(2)|$ among orderings with $|D(0)|=1$, but I wasn't able to deduce much from this.

**Known special cases:** It's not hard to come up with an explicit construction of a strongly regular ordering for any generalized Petersen graph.

Suppose $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle $(v_1,v_2),...,(v_{n-1},v_n),(v_n,v_1)\in E$. A *chordal cycle* is a sequence of nodes $v_i,...,v_j$ such that $(v_i,v_j)\in E$ is a chord. We say $v_{i+1},...,v_{j-1}$ are the interior nodes in this cycle. A *minimal chordal cycle* is a chordal cycle such that no proper subsequence is a chordal cycle.

**Proposition:** If $G$ is $3$-connected and has a Hamiltonian cycle in which every node is contained in the interior of some minimal chordal cycle, then $G$ has a strongly regular ordering.

*Proof:* Let $(v_1,v_2),...,(v_{n-1},v_n),(v_n,v_1)\in E$ be such a Hamiltonian cycle. We define the ordering $w_1<...<w_n$ inductively starting with $w_1=v_1$. Suppose we've chosen $w_1,...,w_t$ such that
$$W := \{w_1,...,w_t\} = \{v_i,v_{i+1},...,v_j\}$$
for some $v_i,v_j$, and $\alpha(w_s)$ is odd for $1<s\leqslant t$. If $v_{j+1} = v_{i-1}$ then we just set $w_n = v_{j+1}$ and we're done; the resulting order has $|D(2)|=0$. If $v_{j+1} = v_{i-2}$ then we set $w_{n-1} = v_{j+1}$ and $w_n= v_{i-1}$; the resulting order has $|D(2)|=1$. If $|N_{v_{j+1}}\cap W|$ is odd we can set $w_{t+1}=v_{j+1}$ and reiterate.

Thus  we can assume $v_{j+1},...,v_{i-1}$ has non-empty interior and $|N_{v_{j+1}}\cap W|$ is even. Since $v_j\in N_{v_{j+1}}\cap W$ we must have $|N_{v_{j+1}}\cap W|=2$. Since $v_{j+2}\notin W$, the only way this can happen is if the chord adjacent to $v_{j+1}$ is adjacent to some node $v_k\in W$.

Let $v_\ell,...,v_m$ be a minimal chordal cycle containing $v_{j+1}$ in its interior. Since $v_k,...,v_{j+1}$ is a chordal cycle and $j+1<m$, we must have $v_k < v_\ell$ by minimality. But then $v_\ell\in\{v_{k+1},...,v_j\}\subseteq W$. Now let $s>j+1$ be minimal such that the chord adjacent to $v_s$ has its other end in $W$. Note that $v_s$ exists and $v_s\neq v_{i-1}$ since otherwise removing $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{j+1}$ would disconnect $G$ (this is where we use $v_{j+1}\neq v_{i-2}$). Thus $v_{s-1},v_{s+1}\notin W$ but the chordal neighbor of $v_s$ is in $W$, so $|N_{v_s}\cap W|=1$. Also we must have $s\leqslant m$ by minimality of $s$. We define $w_{t+1}=v_s$, $w_{t+2}=v_{s-1}$, ..., $w_{t'} = v_{j+1}$. We know $\alpha(w_{t+1})=1$, and $\alpha(w_{t''})>0$ for all $t+1<t''\leqslant t'$ since $w_{t''-1}\in N_{w_{t''}}$. Also clearly $\alpha(w_{t'})=3$. If $t+1<t''<t'$ then $w_{t''} = v_{s'}$ for some $j+1<s'<s$, and by minimality of $s$ the chord adjacent to $v_{s'}$ cannot have its other end in $W$. On the other hand, if this chord has its other end in $\{v_{s'+1},...,v_s\}$ then this would contradict minimality of $v_\ell,...,v_m$.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

I think the hypotheses of the proposition apply for all Honeycomb toroidal graphs; it's certainly true for $HTG(m,2n,\ell)$ when $\ell \leqslant m+2$, and I've also verified it under various arithmetic constraints on $(m,n,\ell)$. The strategy used in the proof also seems to work pretty well even for Hamiltonian cubic graphs that don't satisfy the other hypotheses, but the above hypotheses were the most general I could come up with that guarantee the process will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a graph $G=(V,E)$ is *cyclically $k$-connected* if any subgraph $G=(V,E')$ with $|E|-|E'| < k$ contains at most one component with a cycle.

**Proposition:** Any cyclically $4$-connected cubic graph has a strongly regular ordering.

*Proof:* By Theorem 1.4 of a recent preprint of Nedela-Seifrtová-Škoviera<sup>1</sup>, any cyclically $4$-connected cubic graph $G=(V,E)$ contains a subset $W\subseteq V$ such that the induced subgraph $G[W]$ is a tree and $G[V\setminus W]$ contains at most one edge. Note that under the additional assumption that $|V|\equiv 2\mod 4$ this result appears in an old published paper of Payan and Sakarovitch<sup>1</sup>; under the assumption that $G$ is cyclically $5$-connected the result appears in a recent published paper of Nedela and Škoviera<sup>3</sup>. We'll assume the result of the preprint is correct, but if not the proposition still holds under one of these stronger assumptions.

So let $W\subseteq V$ such that $G[W]$ is a tree and $G[V\setminus W]$ contains at most one edge. We can order the vertices of $G[W]$ such that exactly one node $v_0\in W$ has $\alpha(v_0)=0$ and every $v\neq v_0\in W$ has $\alpha(v)=1$, for example by a breadth-first ordering starting at $v_0$. We can then extend this ordering to $V$ arbitrarily, such that every node in $W$ comes before every node in $V\setminus W$. It's easily verified that the resulting ordering is strongly regular.$\tag*{$\Box$}$

This gives a quite large class of cubic graphs with strongly regular orderings. For example, by a result of Nedela and Škoviera<sup>4</sup> any connected triangle-free cubic graph which is either vertex-transitive or edge-transitive is cyclically $4$-connected. Furthermore it's not terribly hard to show that every graph satisfying the hypotheses of the proposition proved in the question body is cyclically $4$-connected.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Nedela, R.; Seifrtová, M.; Škoviera M.*, [**Decycling cubic graphs**](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.11606), preprint (2023).

<sup>2</sup> *Payan, C.; Sakarovitch, M.*, Ensembles cycliquement stables et graphes cubiques, Cah. Cent. Étud. Rech. Opér. 17, 319-343 (1975). [ZBL0314.05101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0314.05101).

<sup>3</sup> *Nedela, Roman; Škoviera, Martin*, [**Cyclic connectivity, edge-elimination, and the twisted Isaacs graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2022.01.007), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. B 155, 17-44 (2022). [ZBL1487.05144](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1487.05144).

<sup>4</sup> *Nedela, Roman; Škoviera, Martin*, [**Atoms of cyclic connectivity in cubic graphs**](https://eudml.org/doc/32343), Math. Slovaca 45, No. 5, 481-499 (1995). [ZBL0844.05066](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0844.05066).